# Tomcat inside of Docker

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0

ADD target/app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
# So that we can access manager
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Tomcat is running and I can launch the examples, but I cant access my app.

- The war is copied to the container
- The war is also unpacked
- In the tomcat manager I can see it running
- If I use my local tomcat everything works fine

Any ideas on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was really simple, I was confident I had Tomcat 8 locally, but in reality I had 9, updated the dockerfile to use 9.0 and all is well.

Answer (score -1):

Your Dockerfile should contain

```
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: No it should not, I expose the ports in docker-compose and I said that I can access tomcat.